# JumpStartEstimator.fit ERROR: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dataset_train' referenced before assignment

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a simple model tuning python code, when I run I get the fallowing error, appreciate your help.

> ERROR: sagemaker.exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException: Error for
> Training job meta-textgeneration-llama-2-7b-f-2023-11-12-03-11-41-315:
> Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError: ExitCode 1
> ErrorMessage "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dataset_train'
> referenced before assignment

Here is the code snippet:

```
estimator = JumpStartEstimator( model_id=jumpstart_model_name, model_version=jumpstart_model_version, instance_count=Instance_Count, instance_type=InstanceType, environment={"accept_eula": "true"}, role=my_role, region=region_name, sagemaker_session=Sagemaker_Session, max_run =MaxTraining_Time_Sec, input_mode="File", output_path =s3_train_model_path, hyperparameters =my_hyperparameters,
debugger_hook_config=hook_config, tensorboard_output_config=tensorboard_output_config, )

channels = { "training": s3_train_data_path, "test": s3_test_data_path, "validation": s3_val_data_path, }

model tuning :
estimator.fit(inputs=channels, logs="All", wait=True)
```

have tried many things but the error above persists.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the specific model_id you're using.
I suggest to start from a working example (say [this LLAMA2 example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart-foundation-models/llama-2-finetuning.ipynb)) and gradually shape it to match your own need.
Would also immediately remove debugger_hook_config (rarely used).